# Python - double loop for element wise string concatenation

Tags: python, string, concatenation, elementwise-operations

My question is very simple:

I have `A = ['AA','BB']`, `B = ['CC','DD']`

How do I get `AB = ['AACC','AADD','BBCC',BBDD']`?

Thank you!

Comment: What is not working with your attempt?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Hi! I'm just very unfamiliar with python at all.  I was instructed to use a double loop.  But I have no idea where to start.  So this is like a general question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with *list comprehension*:

```
AB = [x + y for x in A for y in B]
```

we thus iterate over the elements in `A` and for each element `x` in `A`, we iterate over `B`, and then add `x + y` to the list.

Or for a variadic number of lists, and with a generator:

```
from itertools import product

map(''.join, product(A, B))
```

This can be easily extended to a variable number of elements, like:

```
>>> A = ['AA','BB']; B = ['CC','DD']; C = ['EE', 'FF']
>>> list(map(''.join, product(A, B, C)))
['AACCEE', 'AACCFF', 'AADDEE', 'AADDFF', 'BBCCEE', 'BBCCFF', 'BBDDEE', 'BBDDFF']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> A = ['AA','BB']
>>> B = ['CC','DD']
>>> AB = [''.join(p) for p in product(A, B)]
>>> AB
['AACC', 'AADD', 'BBCC', 'BBDD']
```

This has the benefit of working with any number of iterables.

Answer (score 2):

Its easier to see whats happening in a complete loop, here we are going to take `i in a` which will be `AA and BB` and `j in b` which will be `CC and DD`. On our first iteration we combine the first two `AA + CC` then `append` them to our new list , next comes  `AA + DD` then onto `BB` and the process repeats.

```
a = ['AA','BB'] 
b = ['CC','DD']

res = []
for i in a:
    for j in b:
        x = i + j
        res.append(x)
print(res)
# ['AACC', 'AADD', 'BBCC', 'BBDD']
```

After you understand this you can skip that process and do it with list comprehension, this is identical.

```
res = [i + j for i in a for j in b]
```

Comment: Thank you! This really helps me understanding the solution.

Comment: @g_tenga no prob take your time with this stuff, don't rush having a solid understanding of `loops` will go a long way when it comes to implementing other solutions